# Ajax submit handler not working , validation working though

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Its a simple form that looks like below:

```html
<form class="form register-form" data-parsley-validate data-parsley-excluded="input[type=button],input[type=submit], input[type=reset]" method="POST">
          <div class="notification hide"></div>
          <div class="row first-rg">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="tfield-2" name="contact_fname" id="contact_fname" placeholder="First Name*" required data-parsley-trigger="focusout">
              <div style="display:none;"><input type="text" class="tfield-2" name="contact_projectname" id="contact_projectname" value="Royal Pearls"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="tfield-2" name="contact_lname" id="contact_lname" placeholder="Last Name*" required data-parsley-trigger="focusout">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row second-rg">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <input type="text" id="contact_phone" placeholder="Phone No. *" name="contact_phone" maxlength="50" required="" class="international-number-input international-phone-number-input intl-phone-number-input" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off" data-parsley-intl-tel-no data-parsley-trigger="focusout" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="email" class="tfield-2" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" placeholder="Email*" data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-trigger="focusout" data-parsley-error-message="Enter Valid Email" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="form-tag">Are you searching for a</p>
          <div class="checkbox regiterpage">
            <label class="background-co">
            <input 
              type="checkbox" 
              value="1" 
              name="bedroom[]"
              required 
              type="checkbox" 
              data-parsley-mincheck="1" 
              data-parsley-error-message="Check atleast 1"
            >
            <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span> 1 Bedroom </label>
            <label class="background-co" >
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="bedroom[]">
            <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span> 2 Bedrooms </label>
            <label class="background-co">
            <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="bedroom[]">
            <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span> 3 Bedrooms </label>
            <label class="background-co">
            <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="bedroom[]">
            <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span> 4 Bedrooms </label>
          </div>
          <div class="radioin">
            <p class="form-tag">Are you searching for a property as an</p>
            <label class="radio-inline background-co">
            <input type="radio" 
            name="propertytype"
            required 
            data-parsley-mincheck="1" 
            data-parsley-error-message="Check atleast 1"
            >
            <span class="rlabl">End-user / Owner-occupier</span> </label>
            <label class="radio-inline background-co">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">
            <span class="rlabl">Investor</span> </label>
          </div>

          <!-- HIDDEN INPUTS FOR google captcha -->
          <input type="hidden" value="No Bots" id="google-captcha" required>
          <input type="hidden"  id="google-captcha-check" data-parsley-equalto="#google-captcha" data-parsley-error-message="Fill the captcha!"  required>
          <!-- HIDDEN INPUTS FOR google captcha -->

          <div class="captch">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdksigUAAAAAKw5idd69Xa3ysK_RZJ3xAleTbVj" data-callback="google_captcha_callback" data-expired-callback="google_captcha_callback"></div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Now i have validated the form using parsely.js , the validation works just fine , but there is a problem with my submit handler, i have the following submit handler in my form:

```js
$('.register-form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mail/reg_send.php',
            data : $('.register-form').serialize(),
            success : (data , status) => {
                (data === 'success') ? $('.notification').text('Thank you for contacting us.').removeClass('hide') : $('.notification').text('There was a problem submitting your form').removeClass('hide');
                $('.register-form')[0].reset();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

But even though i have a submit handler and a return false in the submit handler, the page still refreshes and even the i add a breakpoint to my submit handler in my dev tools , the breakpoint is never reached. Why ? what am i doing wrong here ?

I have tried changing the submit handler to something more generic such as:

```
$('form').submit((){
   // code here
})
```

But my page will still refreah. Why ?

Comment: Does console show any errors?

Comment: try putting an e in the function(e) and use e.PreventDefault() instead of return false.

Comment: yes `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at Object._.ig (js?key=AIzaSyBZ8sIAeHlcSlygM3AGuazth2hMmsIy7q8:84)
    at new ng (js?key=AIzaSyBZ8sIAeHlcSlygM3AGuazth2hMmsIy7q8:86)
    at init (map.js:149)` on page load ... but this is unrelated ! :)

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP?

Comment: um, what you changed it to the end is not valid....

Comment: So does your code actually find a form? Is the form dynamic?

Comment: @epascarello no the form is static .

Comment: Well your page has a JavaScript error on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the event in the handler with `function(e)` and [prevent default](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on it.

```
$('.register-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // the rest of your code
});
```

Your other problem might be that your event handler is not being attached to the element because it is not available when the JavaScript is executed. You can test this easily by using the following instead:

```
$(document).on("submit", ".register-form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // the rest of your code
});
```